# How to record HTML canvas only when stream.requestFrame() gets called, and save result?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video-capture, mediarecorder

I'm trying to record a HTML canvas animation using [canvas.captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream).

However, I don't want to record the canvas live.

Instead, I want to record on a per-frame basis, only once the canvas has been fully drawn.

In order to record on a per-frame basis, I provide a framerate of 0 by using canvas.captureStream(0).
This should make it so a frame is only captured when [stream.requestFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack/requestFrame) is called.

However, I have no idea what to do from here to access the stream, or save it as a video file. Ideally I could use MediaRecorder, but [MediaRecorder.ondataavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) is not synchronized with requestFrame(). This means it records everything, ignoring requestFrame() entirely.

Below is an example illustrating my issue:

```js
let stream;
let recording;
let downloadButton;
let chunks = [];
let recorder;
let interval;

function setup() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    recording = document.getElementById("recording");
    downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    stream = canvas.captureStream(0);
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
            chunks.push(event.data);
        }
    }
    recorder.onstop = function() {
        let recordedBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/webm" });
        recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
        downloadButton.href = recording.src;
        downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
    }
}

function toggleAnimation() {
    if (interval) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        recorder.stop();
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        interval = undefined;
    } else {
        // I know this could be animated a lot faster, but this is just an example
        // Imagine something like raytracing, where it takes much longer to render a frame
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 + (Math.random() * 50), canvas.height / 2 + (Math.random() * 50), 32, 32);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.font = "16px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("How can I get this to capture frames", 16, 16);
          ctx.fillText("only when requestFrame() is called?", 16, 32);
            // This ideally would capture only the moving frames
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].requestFrame();
        }, 500); // Example delay of 0.5 seconds between frames
        recorder.start();
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="setup();">
    <input type="button" value="Play and Record Animation / Stop and Save Recording" onclick="toggleAnimation();">
    <a id="downloadButton" class="button">Download Video</a>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
        <video id="recording" width="320" height="240" controls></video>
  </div>
</body>
```

Although the delay in this example could be avoided by lowering the time delay, imagine a situation such as ray-tracing where there would be a much more significant lag between frames. This is the type of issue I am trying to get around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!